# If we use assertEquals, is it worth to make a check for assertNotNull first in Junit test cases?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a test cases as below:

```
 @Test
    public void GIVEN_correct_tradingStatusId_parameter_WHEN_invoked_getTradingStatusByName_THEN_correct_TradingStatus_is_returned() {
        String tradingStatus = lookupDto.getTradingStatusByName("2013");

        assertNotNull(tradingStatus);
        assertEquals("Dissolved", tradingStatus);
    }
```

Here I am testing for tradingStatus not to be null and then checking it equals to `Dissolved`.
My concern is do I actually need to test `assertNotNull` if I am testing using `assertEquals`.

I went through the method definition for assertEquals in sourcecode. It is as below:-

```
static public void assertEquals(String message, Object expected,
            Object actual) {
        if (equalsRegardingNull(expected, actual)) {
            return;
        } else if (expected instanceof String && actual instanceof String) {
            String cleanMessage = message == null ? "" : message;
            throw new ComparisonFailure(cleanMessage, (String) expected,
                    (String) actual);
        } else {
            failNotEquals(message, expected, actual);
        }
    }
```

In this **equalsRegardingNull** is like :

```
private static boolean equalsRegardingNull(Object expected, Object actual) {

    if (expected == null) {
        return actual == null;
    }
    return isEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

I am not able to understand even from this whether it is worth to use `assertNotNull` before calling `assertEquals`. Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is NO.

No there is no need to use `assertNotNull` before `assertEquals`. If your `tradingStatus` is `null` the comparison will anyway fail and will tell you that you are comparing against `null`. Everything else makes your test code just more complex but brings no extra benefit in return.

Comment: Note however that two null strings will still work for assertEquals:   @Test void null_equals() { assertEquals((String) null, (String) null); }

Answer (score 4):

You should try to dig deep `isEqual` method, you will find:

```
private static boolean isEquals(Object expected, Object actual) {
    return expected.equals(actual);
}
```

so you will find it's comparing by using `expected.equals` method, and since `expected` checks `null` firstly, by:

```
if (expected == null) {
    return actual == null;
}
```

and it avoids the `NullPointerException` in `expected.equals`, it's safe to compare.

So it's unnecessary to manually check `actual`(*tradingStatus*) null by `assertNotNull(tradingStatus);`.

Comment: No! `expected == null` check is checking for expected to be null not actual to be null.

Comment: @VinayPrajapati, Yes, it's for **compare null**, but also for avoid `NullPointerException` when you use `expected` to compare `actual`

Comment: I think `isEquals(expected, actual)` is doing that comparison for us for which calls `expected.equals(actual)`. Not convinced actually.